# Android: Add searchView on the Action Bar

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-actionbar, searchview

My Complete Project Is As Follows: There is a **listView** connnected to database and a **search option with suggestion**. I wanna **shift this search bar to the action bar** and format it just like **Google Play Store Search bar**. Please help me, my complete codes are:

***MainActivity.java***

```
package com.GurbaniAndSikh.MahaanKosh;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;

/*
 * Created by GurbaniAndSikh
 */

public class DictionaryMainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    private static RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public static ArrayList<DictObjectModel> data;
    DatabaseHelper db ;
    ArrayList<String> wordcombimelist;
    ArrayList<String> meancombimelist;
    LinkedHashMap<String,String> namelist;
    SearchView searchView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        db= new DatabaseHelper(this);
        searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.searchView);
        searchView.setQueryHint("Search Here");
        searchView.setQueryRefinementEnabled(true);
        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        data = new ArrayList<DictObjectModel>();
        fetchData();


        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {return  false; }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {


                newText = newText.toLowerCase();

                final ArrayList<DictObjectModel> filteredList = new ArrayList<DictObjectModel>();

                for (int i = 0; i < wordcombimelist.size(); i++) {

                    final String text = wordcombimelist.get(i).toLowerCase();
                    if (text.contains(newText)) {

                        filteredList.add(new DictObjectModel(wordcombimelist.get(i),meancombimelist.get(i)));
                    }
                }
                adapter = new CustomAdapter(filteredList);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);


                return true;
            }
        });


    }
    public void fetchData()
    {
        db =new DatabaseHelper(this);
        try {

            db.createDataBase();
            db.openDataBase();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        namelist=new LinkedHashMap<>();
        int ii;
        SQLiteDatabase sd = db.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sd.query("Dictionary1" ,null, null, null, null, null, null);
        ii=cursor.getColumnIndex("word");
        wordcombimelist=new ArrayList<String>();
        meancombimelist= new ArrayList<String>();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()){
            namelist.put(cursor.getString(ii), cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("definition")));
        }
        Iterator entries = namelist.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry thisEntry = (Map.Entry) entries.next();
            wordcombimelist.add(String.valueOf(thisEntry.getKey()));
            meancombimelist.add("- "+String.valueOf(thisEntry.getValue()));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < wordcombimelist.size(); i++) {
          data.add(new DictObjectModel(wordcombimelist.get(i), meancombimelist.get(i)));
          }
        adapter = new CustomAdapter(data);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

I use these codes to add searchView to action bar but getfilter() doesn't work.

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.menuSearch);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

                return false;
            }
        });

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

**Please Tell Me How I Approach To My Target Please Help Me**

Comment: http://javapapers.com/android/android-searchview-action-bar-tutorial/
Have a look on this Blog! He explains quite good, how to create a search bar. Or ask a specific question to a problem you have. If you need someone to develop it for you look on upster.com.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a search view in option menu then use it by overriding `onCreateOptionsMenu()` programmatically.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
        android:title="Search"/>
</menu>
```

Later in Activity class,

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        MenuItem myActionMenuItem = menu.findItem( R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) myActionMenuItem.getActionView();
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                    adapter.filter("");
                    listView.clearTextFilter();
                } else {
                    adapter.filter(newText);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });

        return true;
    }
```