# How to add a SearchView in an ActionBar on NativeScript Android (like WhatsApp)?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, nativescript, searchview, searchbar

I would like to add a SearchView in an ActionBar on **NativeScript Android**.

The same shown in the Material Design Guide and used on WhatsApp when you click on the search icon.

Below are examples that I can not "convert" for NativeScript:

[How to implement SearchView in ActionBar in Android](http://codesfor.in/how-to-implement-searchview-in-actionbar-in-android/)

[Android: Add searchView on the Action Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41867961/android-add-searchview-on-the-action-bar)

[Android - Using SearchView in Toolbar/ActionBar with "Gmail style" ListView](http://www.devexchanges.info/2016/05/android-using-searchview-in.html)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will add SearchBar to ActionBar and toggle it's visibility just like the example you linked.

**XML**

```
<ActionBar title="Home">
    <SearchBar visibility="{{ show, show ? 'visible' : 'hidden' }}"
        clear="onToggleSearchBar">
    </SearchBar>
    <ActionItem visibility="{{ show, show ? 'hidden' : 'visible' }}"
        text="Search" tap="onToggleSearchBar"></ActionItem>
</ActionBar>
```

**TS**

```
export function onToggleSearchBar(args: EventData) {
    (args.object as any).bindingContext.show = !(args.object as any).bindingContext.show;
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
export class HomeViewModel extends Observable {
    @ObservableProperty() show: boolean = false;

    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}
```

[Playground Sample](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-tsc&id=ZPl1jM)

Comment: Thank you @Manoj :)