# How to add search filter in custom adapter in listview with images?

Tags: java, android

Sorry I am new in Java and I used the following code in **MainActivity** and **Custom adapter** after researching how listview is created. I have tried so many ways to create searchView in actionbar by doing a lot of research, maybe is because I am new in Java and I lack understanding of the language.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ARAOV.jpg)

**MainActivity code**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView lv;
    Context context;

    public static int[] prgmImages = {
            R.drawable.ic_f"
    };

    public static String[] prgmNameList = {
            "Bakoena"
    };

    public static String[] liphoofolo = {
            "Ba ana koena."
    };

    public static String[] phoofolo = {
            "Koena ke phoofolo e lulang metsing e phelang ka ho ja nama ea liphoofolo"
    };

    @SuppressLint("CutPasteId")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Make sure this is before calling super.onCreate
        setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        //custom statusbar for each activity
        /*if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            window.setStatusBarColor(Color.RED);
        }*/

        context = this;

        lv = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, prgmNameList, liphoofolo, phoofolo, prgmImages));
}
}
```

**Custom Adapter code**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    String [] result;
    String [] results;
    String [] resultss;
    Context context;
    int [] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public CustomAdapter(MainActivity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, String[] liphoofolo, String[] phoofolo, int[] prgmImages) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result=prgmNameList;
        results=liphoofolo;
        resultss=phoofolo;
        context=mainActivity;
        imageId=prgmImages;
        inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public static class Holder
    {
        TextView tv;
        TextView ts;
        TextView tss;
        ImageView img;
    }
    @SuppressLint({"ViewHolder", "InflateParams"})
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder= new Holder();
        View rowView;

        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.program_list, null);
        holder.tv= rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.ts= rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.tss= rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        holder.img= rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.ts.setText(results[position]);
        holder.tss.setText(resultss[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);

        return rowView;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new android resource directory called `menu` resource type `menu` in the res folder (lef click on res folder > new > android resource directory). Inside create menu resource file called `menu_bar` (again lef click on menu folder > new > menu resource file) in the file inside menu tag add the falling code:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
```

Then in main activity add:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_bar, menu);

        MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.app_bar_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)item.getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
            return false;
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

or https://stackoverflow.com/a/41868020/7735363

Comment: Thanks. SearchView shows fine but it cannot filter my list, how to make it filter list with images using the code above?

Comment: Sorry I  have no idea how to intergrate these two codes, above code in custom adapter and the code from the link you provided. The point is everything works fine however the problem is to implement working searchView in actionbar using  above custom adapter because if I change it my code will affect the whole project.